# How to enter a new connection string in MongoDB Compass Newer Version 1.39.0

Tags: mongodb, connection, database-connection, connection-string, mongodb-compass

[Here is latest version screenshot of how to get the connection string for this connection named as local in my machine!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBBKb.png)

In the previous version we could easily connect Compass to Database simply by clicking 'manually enter connection string' option but in this newer version I don't know how to do the same?

#Note : I want to use local MongoDB server that is installed on my own local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The process of connecting compass with the local database server is first you will have to create a new connection.
This connection will be saved in the Compass untill you delete it.

You can simply connect using existing connection, as shown in the screenshot you need to simply click on connect.

To add an new connection, you will have to click on new connection, there you will get an option to enter the connection string manually. Enter your connection string and add new connection and then connect to the database server.

The screenshot that you posted shows an existing connection saved to your local mongodb instance, you can directly connect to it by simply clicking on the connect button and no need to add yet another connection.